# How to locate element in Selenium with attribute only, irrespective of the what value attribute holds

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

How to locate an element in Selenium with attribute only?

An element in DOM is as below:

```
<div data-test="test" data-app-test="xyz">
```

I can form the XPath as below:

```
//div[@data-app-test="xyz"]
```

but the problem is that @data-app-test can have dynamic value, so I want to locate an element which contains attribute "data-app-test", but its value can be anything. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS Selector:

```
div[data-app-test]
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to classic CSS .. it's about selenium and xpath

Comment: @TemaniAfif Without a attribute value or a parent reference this isn't a classic CSS but as per the HTML and condition provided  by OP there can be hardly any other way other than Ratmir's Answer :/

Comment: @DebanjanB if it was about CSS an html this is the anwser i would also provide ... but the question is about selenium and xpath, so this answer should be the correct one https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753384/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif OP didn't specifically request an XPath, he requested a locator and provided a sample XPath. If you look at the tags, he added xpath AND css (corrected to css-selector) which would seem to indicate that he is looking for either. Add to that he selected this answer with a CSS selector, I think he's open to either... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just specify the attribute exists, don't compare its value to anything:

```
//div[@data-app-test]
```

Comment: I tried this xpath it was not working, even in firebug it was not able to locate the element. CSS selector worked perfectly fine for me

Comment: Works for me in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh).

Answer (score 0):

You can do quite not good in term of performance but let's say for some cases reliable way:

1) Find a root element(container) that contains all `<div>`s;

2) `driver.findElement(containerLocator)
.findElements(locatorDiv)
.forEach(element -> "yourAttribute".equals(element.getAttribute(attribute)))`.

So main idea to use element.getAttribute(NAME).

Another way just use XPath for selection.

For example, `//node[not(@*)]` this should return all elements without attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply retrieve using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-test='test']")).getAttribute("data-app-test");
```

Comment: i am not aware about waht value dynamic element has , my intention to locate the element is to get that dynamic value and based on it proceed further in code

Comment: @AkashChavan Refer edited answer, Earlier was regarding attribute name which I thought, This is regarding attribute value.

Comment: value in first attribute is also not unique, it may change any time. So this approach cannot be used. I was able to locate it by css selector

Answer (score 0):

@* is short for attribute::* and selects all attributes of the context node:

```
  //div[@*]
```